# C# Creating 8-bit binary number and bit manipulation

Tags: c#, .net, io, bit-manipulation

I am creating a WPF program with C# that will be talking to an I/O board. In order to write data to the I/O board I need to pass a 8-bit binary number (1111 1111 means all 8 output ports are "off" where as 0000 0000 means all 8 output ports are "on"). I have checkboxes that toggle these output ports by writing data in the form of that 8-bit number. Here is an example of my current code:

```
private void sol1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            switch (io_boards_list.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    if (sol2.IsChecked == true)
                    {
                        USBIOBoards.io_boards.WritePort(0, 16, 0xFC); // 1111 1100
                    } else
                    {
                        USBIOBoards.io_boards.WritePort(0, 16, 0xFE); // 1111 1110
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void sol1_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // 1111 1111
            switch (io_boards_list.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    if (sol2.IsChecked == true)
                    {
                        USBIOBoards.io_boards.WritePort(0, 16, 0xFD); // 1111 1101
                    } else
                    {
                        USBIOBoards.io_boards.WritePort(0, 16, 0xFE); // 1111 1111
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

The issue right now is that if I were to tick the first checkbox and then the second one, the I/O board will not keep the first signal on with the second one but instead disable the signal because of the absolute nature of how the data is written. I'd like to be able to see something up where I can just have a variable hold 1111 1111 and I can modify a single-bit at its location so that I can have more than one output signal be on. I'm relatively new with C# so I'm not sure how to approach this problem efficiently. I could always brute force it but I'd like to avoid that as we will be porting this software to many custom machines that may have different ports and whatnot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should familiarize yourself with the binary operators (| & ^) For instance you can toggle the least significant bit of a number by XOR'ing it with 00000001:

```
x = x ^ 0b00000001;
```

Comment: It's crazy how this always seems to happen but after spending about an hour trying to figuring it out and asking the question here, I was able to find the solution right after which was basically your answer. I'm able to just toggle each bit individually and that solved my problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The application below uses bitmasking to set or clear bits.

You can create a new Console Application project with visual studio and cut and paste the code below.

```
using System;

namespace Bitmanipulation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int value = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{Convert.ToString(value, toBase: 2),8}");
                value = value.SetBit(i, true);
            }

            for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                value = value.SetBit(i, false);
                Console.WriteLine($"{Convert.ToString(value, toBase: 2),8}");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public static class BitManipulation
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Extension method
        /// Sets or clears a bit in a value
        /// The pos = a zero base position in the value counted from the right
        /// </summary>
        public static int SetBit(this int val, int pos, bool onoff)
        {
            // Shift a bit to the position you want to set or clear
            int mask = 1 << pos;
            // Depending on set or clearing use the mask or a reversed one
            mask = onoff ? mask : 0x7fffffff ^ mask;
            // Depending on set of clearing do a bitwise OR or AND
            return onoff ? val | mask : val & mask; 
        }
    }
}
```

Output of the application:

```
       0
       1
      11
     111
    1111
   11111
  111111
 1111111
 1111111
  111111
   11111
    1111
     111
      11
       1
       0
```